# How do I format the colour of a cell if the value is NULL in Reporting Services 2008 R2?

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

In Reporting Services 2008 R2, in a Tablix I have the following code that changes the background colour dependant on the value:

```
=switch(Fields!Mean_Difference.Value > 0,"#DA9694",
        Fields!Mean_Difference.Value = 0,"#FCD5B4",
        Fields!Mean_Difference.Value < 0,"#C4D79B")
```

However when there is a NULL value it formats it the same colour as if it is equal to 0, the problem is that I do not want it to be formatted, just left blank. I have tried using isNothing() with no luck and cannot seem to find an answer.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work? (you should use Nothing for transparent background in ssrs). Are you sure that the value is definitely null?

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!Mean_Difference.Value)
,Nothing
,switch(Fields!Mean_Difference.Value > 0,"#DA9694",
    Fields!Mean_Difference.Value = 0,"#FCD5B4",
    Fields!Mean_Difference.Value < 0,"#C4D79B"))
```

Comment: Yes the value is definitely NULL. It Works! Excellent thank you!